# Consequences of magic allowing biochemistry to happen at range

Tags: magic, chemistry, biochemistry

I have a mage who's trying to connect his "life force" to another person's in order to magically heal them.  Mechanically, this happens by the mage allowing his patient's body's biomolecules to react with his own—he's magically able to let the two bodies' biomolecules interact at range.

I am not a biologist, nor a chemist.  I *think* that this would allow the patient's body to use the mage's body's chemical energy and enzymes.  Would this work as intended, or would there be unintended consequences to this alteration of chemistry?  For example, would I need to think up a way to prevent every molecule in the patient's body suddenly trying to react with every other molecule?

Comment: I don't know what "biomolecules" means. Every molecule in the body is a "biomolecule," isn't it? It's a bit like saying the mage goes out of phase so that his body and the patient's body can occupy the same space at the same time (perhaps not unlike a blood transfusion....). But, without a much better definition of what "mechanically" is going on and an explanation of your magic system, this is a hard question to answer.

Comment: As stated, wouldn't this basically be no different than healing normally except it can draw vital materials from the other's cells? Nothing in that particular magical interaction would do anything to increase healing rate in a normal scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest problem here is going to be the immune system. The "is-everything-going-to-react-with-everything-else" question is probably not an issue---cells are very compartmentalized, and if you maintain that same basic structure you should be good (after all, the molecules in your arms don't constantly react with those in your eyes). I think that the best precedent for this would probably be organ transplants, where a huge problem is keeping the recipient from rejecting the organ. In order for this to work, you'll have to, at least at first, suppress the immune systems of both the mage and the target. Other than that, you should probably check basic compatibility things like blood type, and whether either has any diseases that could cause problems (chronic illness, genetic disorders, cancer, etc.). If you can work around the immune system issue, I think that it's a really cool idea!

Answer (score 1):

**This will likely kill the patient and has the potential to kill the caster as well**

There's a principle in chemistry called Le Chatelier's principle, which states that all systems tend towards equilibrium. If you had a room which had a left half of oxygen and the right half of nitrogen gas, then what would happen is that the two would spread out over the room so all the room would be a mixture of both oxygen and nitrogen. Simple enough, right?

The human body uses this principle for pretty much *everything*. One of the really important things in a human body is a concentration gradient, in other words, since things tend toward an equilibrium, your body can use that fact to power certain reactions. Mitochondria, for instance, use a surplus of H+ ions to power the ATP synthase pump. Nerve cells will ion channels found within the cell membrane to regulate itself. Etc, etc, etc.

Now, if you gave the ability to the subject to interact with *your* body, magically, from a distance, you've bypassed the concentration gradient - as in, *all of them*. Since your patient is drawing energy from the caster, using the caster's steroids, enzymes, ATP, what-have-you, even if you somehow managed to perfectly line up the spell so that only the molecules that are supposed to interact with each other do (and that feat exceeds modern medical knowledge, by the way), then you're going to disastrously screw with the patients internal biochemistry and homeostasis and likely leave a backlash so severe that it will kill the patient. And, depending on how badly the patient's drain affect the caster's own internal workings, it may kill the caster as well.

tl;dr - human are really complex and a general spell of 'make all the biomolecules react with another' does more harm than good.